# SQL Server finding the recommended datatype and length for columns in a table

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a time consuming task that I am looking to do quickly, I'm open to either t-sql or a nice python library/script suggestion if there is one.

Lets say you have a table with x number of columns some could be date datatype, some nvarchar, and some int. But having been imported from a flat file (CSV in this case), all the columns were set to nvarchar(4000), just to get the data in. Now tables using the correct datatype and/or length now need to be created. I was wondering if there is anything that can iterate through the columns and identify the best datatype, and report back what would be the best length based on the longest entry it finds in a column.

Currently I am doing this manually, using convert, one column at a time. If it converts great, length-wise I am using len. Might see if I can use foreachtable somehow, but thought I'd ask in case some genius out there has been awesome and created something for us to use already. I did a google, but didn't find what I was looking for. Thank you for reading, and any suggestions are most welcome and appreciated.
Regards,D

Comment: Creating a table schema should not be an automated process because you do it once in your project and put a lot of thought in it.

Comment: While inferring data types from content might seem like an easy task, it's actually pretty hard to do it correctly. Using an script to automate that for you can probably infer the correct data type most of the time, but you will still have to go through the result manually to catch mistakes. Also, the max/min values are very easy to get wrong - if you go with what you have in the current file, and in the next file you'll get a string larger than the largest string you currently have - you'll need to adjust. same goes with tinyint / smallint / int and bigint, of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back, I kind of already knew I'd have to take the long way round on this, its better in the long run. Thanks again.